# I've been try to plot this function but it's not work. It's in the body

Tags: functions

```
Plot[z^7 - 5*z^4 + 3*z^2 + 6*z - 4, {z, -2 - 2*I, 2 + 2*I}]
```

Comment: `Plot` does not plot complex numbers.  Instead, plot the real and imaginary parts of your expression.

Comment: To plot for complex values of `z` with version 12 you can use [`ComplexPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexPlot.html) or [`ComplexPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexPlot3D.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
Plot[ReIm[(-2 + I x)^7 - 5 (-2 + I x)^4 + 3 (-2 + I x)^2 + 
   6 (-2 + I x) - 4], {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: You can add `Evaluate` and labels for better representation: `Plot[Evaluate@ReIm[(-2 + I x)^7 - 5 (-2 + I x)^4 + 3 (-2 + I x)^2 + 6 (-2 + I x) - 4], {x, -2, 2}, PlotLabels -> {"Re", "Im"}]`